# babel rewire not replacing fetch variable

Tags: node.js, module, require, babeljs

I have isolated my issue with `babel-plugin-rewire` to these few files. I am trying to figure out why `console.log(dep)` is still logging fetch as a function and not `true` as it should have been replaced.

> .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "babel-preset-stage-3",
    [
      "babel-preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "4.0.0"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-rewire"
  ]
}
```

> dep.js

```
const fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch')

module.exports = {fetch}
```

> use.js

```
const dep = require('./dep')

dep.__Rewire__('fetch', true)

console.log(dep)
```

> package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node ./use.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-rewire": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just learned the hard way that `rewire` doesn't change module scope (duh).

> dep.js

```
var Path = require('path');

var env = 'production';

console.log(env)

module.exports = function(name) {
  console.log(env)
  return Path.normalize(name)
}
```

> use.js

```
var normalizer = require('./dep.js');

normalizer.__Rewire__('Path', {
  normalize: (name) => name
});

console.log(normalizer('/foo/bar//baz/asdf/quux/..'))

normalizer.__Rewire__('env', 'testing');

console.log(normalizer('/foo/bar//baz/asdf/quux/..'))

normalizer.__ResetDependency__('Path');

console.log(normalizer('/foo/bar//baz/asdf/quux/..'))
```

logs:

```
production
production
/foo/bar//baz/asdf/quux/..
testing
/foo/bar//baz/asdf/quux/..
testing
/foo/bar/baz/asdf
```